# How to read string with spaces, integers and float values from a file in c?

Tags: c, gcc

Hi first of all let me be precise, I have a data file in following format:

[image: sample file]

The first line contains a string followed by three integers and a float data type. 
The second line contains string with a space followed by three integers and a float data type.
The last row contains a string followed by three integers and a float data type.

My aim is to read these data and assign to an array of structure, a structure in an array contains one row with string, 3 integers and one float number.
I tied using the following code and got succeeded  to read a line where string has no space, but cannot read string with spaces:

```
void readFromDatabase(struct student temp[], int *no) {
    FILE *filepointer;
    int i = 0;
    if ((filepointer = fopen("database", "r")) == NULL) {
        printf("Read error");
        return;
    }
    while (fscanf(filepointer, "%10s\t%d%d%d%f\n", temp[i].name,
            &temp[i].birthday.date, &temp[i].birthday.month,
            &temp[i].birthday.year, &temp[i].gpa) != EOF && i < MAX_CLASS_SIZE) {
        ++i;
    }
    *no = i;
    fclose(filepointer);
}
```

I got the follwing output which was unexpected:

[image: Unexpected output]

I was trying to loop through the structure array and display the data in above format.

But instead of getting 3 rows of output i got 4 rows.

I really need some help on this topic.

Thanks in advance...


And i am using gcc under ubuntu 16.04 for compiling and executing the program..

Comment: C++ or c? Pick a language 1st please. Your code looks like plain c.

Comment: it is c programming. plain c.

Comment: `fscanf` returns the number of matching parameters.

Comment: You can't have "a float data type" in a text file. You have a number, in human-readable decimal notation. It's really important that you understand this distinction.

Comment: If it is C, please **do not** tag C++. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `fscanf` format string, use `%10[^\t]` instead of `%10s`. This matches each character of the name until the tabulator separator.

Unfortunately, you did not give a full example, so this is my small program to test on Ubuntu 16.04:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX_CLASS_SIZE 4

struct student {
        char name[11];
        struct {
                int date;
                int month;
                int year;
        } birthday;
        float gpa;
};

int main(void) {
        FILE *filepointer;
        int i = 0;
        int no;
        struct student temp[MAX_CLASS_SIZE];
        if ((filepointer = fopen("data.txt", "r")) == NULL) {
                printf("Read error");
                return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
        while (fscanf(filepointer, "%10[^\t]\t%d%d%d%f\n", temp[i].name,
                                &temp[i].birthday.date, &temp[i].birthday.month,
                                &temp[i].birthday.year, &temp[i].gpa) != EOF && i < MAX_CLASS_SIZE) {
                ++i;
        }
        no = i;
        fclose(filepointer);

        for(i = 0; i < no; i++) {
                printf("%s: %d-%d-%d %f\n",
                        temp[i].name,
                        temp[i].birthday.date, temp[i].birthday.month, temp[i].birthday.year,
                        temp[i].gpa
                );
        }
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Based on your format string, I am assuming that all values in your database are separated by tabulators.

Comment: Thats working perfectly, but if string consists of three spaces and more than 10 characters, then again the row below is not working correctly

Comment: First, if it is more than 10 characters it fails because that doesn't match with the pattern, which requires "a string with up to ten characters that are no tabulator" -- this has nothing to with the three spaces.

Comment: You can increase the maximum number of characters to whatever size your `.name` field has (minus 1 for the NUL-byte).

Second, you should listen to [mch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39766796/how-to-read-string-with-spaces-integers-and-float-values-from-a-file-in-c/39767283?noredirect=1#comment66828469_39766796) in order to handle the error when `fscanf()` fails. I'd guess that you need to consume the rest of the line in that case.

Comment: Is there is any way to consume rest of the line  konrad sir??

Comment: Well, read from the file until you reached the next newline character, e.g. `while((c = fgetc(filepointer)) != '\n' && c != EOF) {}`.  

(I did not test that. You may need to add some error handling.)

Comment: Hi @user3213732 if this answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.